Travel to other Schengen countries with Residence Permit from a Schengen country
I have a US passport. If I obtain a resident permit (temporary or permanent) in one Schengen country (let's say Germany), can I travel freely to other Schengen countries without being subject to the 90 day in 180 day period restriction?

Your edited in line is answered by the duplicate, officially you need to keep to the 90/180 rules but in practice you will not get stamps so it is not looked at in as much detail.


can I travel freely to other Schengen countries?

Yes, with a Schengen residence permit you can travel to other Schengen countries with your passport and residence permit card.
While outside of the issuing country (Germany), the 90 days in any 180-day period rule applies.
The main difference is that you will have no entry/exit stamp in your passport, so the rule is effectivly not enforced.
The residence permit card explains the reason why your passport has no entry/exit stamps in case any checks are made.
